# Is it possible to make api calls from a model in Angular?

Tags: angular

Say I have an angular application with a service: UserService. The service is used to interact with our backend like this:

```
getUser(userId: string) {
    return this.http.get<User>(this.endPoint + '/user/' + userId).pipe(
        map(data => new User().deserialize(data)),
        catchError(() => throwError('User not found'))
    );
}
```

The result is then translated to an actual user obj (like discussed here: https://nehalist.io/angular-7-models/).

The user model could look like this:

```
import {Deserializable} from './deserializable.model';

export class User implements Deserializable {
  public id: number;
  public firstName: string;
  public lastName: string;
  public position: string;

  deserialize(input: any): this {
   ....
  }

  getFullName() {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
  }
}
```

Now I would like to extend this model with some api functions. For example it would be nice to have a user.refresh() function, that would reach out to the backend to check for changes on the user obj. But I cannot inject the UserService (or the HttpService for that matter) since my model is not an injectable class?

Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you want to put such logic in a model? Usually, a model is meant to be a **model** which should not contain such stuff

Comment: It would bring a lot of convenience and readability in the code, to be able to call user.save(), user.refresh(), user.getFriends() etc..

Comment: The model means the interface is normally used to define the datatype. it should be implemented in services or component.

Comment: I disagree - it would mix up model with service layer without apparent reason. After all userService.save(user) is as readable as user.save)

Comment: OK I understand. It makes sense, that models should concentrate on the data(-model). I might also have simplified my question too much. Please check my new question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make api calls from a model in Angular?

Ofcourse it is possible but the question is should it be done?

Since you already try to have separate layers of logic, this would only break that separation as for no apparent reason model entity `User` would start to be network dependent. It would be far better to include required functionality in your `UserService` than in `User` itself.

This way you would achieve your goal of extending functionality and keep your code clean.